# Trying to use ggplot to map data points onto a shapefile

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

So I've had this problem for a few days now. Basically what I have is a table with Field Site latitudes/longitudes represented as numerics. Associated with each Site Id is different chemical data that I want to plot. Here is what the table looks like.
[Table Description][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4vH5.png

I've also uploaded a shapefile. 
[Shapefile][2][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDFca.png

Now what I want to do is plot these data points with these chemical data unto the map using ggplot. I first used the code

```
    Master_cave_data <- Master_cave_data %>%
    st_as_sf(coords = c('Long_DD', 'Lat_DD'), crs = 4326, sf_column_name = NULL)
```

This worked and I also converted the data set into a data frame using the code

```
    Master_cave_data <- as.data.frame(Master_cave_data)
```

But I still can't plot the data points onto the shape file. Do I have to plot them using tmap?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `geom_sf()` in your ggplot call to [plot sf objects](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html). You don't even need the `as.data.frame` conversion.

```
ggplot(Master_cave_data) +
geom_sf()
```

Comment: I had tried using geom_sf() on then geom_points() on the data points that I want plot. But kept on getting this error 'Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class gg/ggplot'

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: thank you for the help but I figured it out and you were right that all I needed was geom_sf. The problem wasn't with my code, but my data. My shapefile was using northing/easting while I was plotting my points with latitude/longitude. Lol all that trouble